# Не получается поставить ссылку в слайдере на изображение, подскажите как это можно реализовать

Tags: javascript, html, cms, slider

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12 foto" id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider_top">
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wa-data/public/site/themes/1.jpg);">
            <a href="http://www.webasyst.ru/store/theme/flamingo/instruktsiya/">

            </a>                
        </div>
        <div class="slide"  style="background-image: url(/wa-data/public/site/themes/2.jpg);">
                            <a href="http://amulet-td.ru/">
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wa-data/public/site/themes/slide1-980x340.png);">
            <a href="http://www.webasyst.ru/store/theme/flamingo/instruktsiya/">
            <!--    <div class="slide-block">

                </div>-->
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wa-data/public/site/themes/slide2-980x340.png);">
            <a href="http://www.webasyst.ru/store/theme/flamingo/instruktsiya/">

            </a>                
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(/wa-data/public/site/themes/slide3-980x340.png);">
            <a href="http://www.webasyst.ru/store/theme/flamingo/instruktsiya/">

            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

тэг  по дефолту является inline элементом, поэтому он будет расширятся по размеру того, что у него внутри.
Либо воспользуйтесь советом от @lexxl либо задайте css свойства

```
height: 100%;
display: block;
```

Высота будет 100% от родителя, а свойство block растянет элемент на всей ширине так же относительно родителя, ***если у него не стоит свойство float: left;.**

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вам необходимо использовать вместо `style="background-image: url(...)` стандартный тег для картинок `<img src="...">`, облачённый в тег `<a href="">`:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12 foto" id="wrapper">
<div id="slider_top">
 <div class="slide">
  <a href="http://www.webasyst.ru/store/theme/flamingo/instruktsiya/">
   <img src="/wa-data/public/site/themes/1.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
...
```